# Angular ng-show expression refers to html content

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to format addresses that have components missing, like

```
{{name}}<br/>
{{street}}<br/>
{{cityStateZip}}<br/>
```

**Edit** - my "street" expression might actually look like this:

```
{{address.number}} {{address.street}} {{address.apartment}}<br ng-show="address.number && address.number.trim().length>0 && address.street && address.street.trim().length > 0"
```

and so on.

Some of the address components are optional, like some addresses won't have a street.  For those, I don't want a line break.  I think I can do this:

```
{{street}}<br ng-show="street.length == 0"/>
```

but, the expression for street might be more complex (like number and street) and it might be undefined or it might be an empty string.  As a result, all those ng-show expressions will become long and redundant.

So what I'd really like is a show expression that refers to the tag's contents, like:

```
<span ng-show="thisTagsContents.length>0">{{some expression}}<br/><span>
```

...where, if it existed, "thisTagsContents" is equivalent to the rendered output of "some expression".  Do I have to make my own directive for this, or is there something already in angular to help?  Or maybe I'm thinking about it the wrong way altogether?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just `<br ng-show="street == true" />`? `undefined`, the empty string `""` and the empty array `[]` are all falsy values.

Comment: Can you further explain at which point you think that your expression gets too complicated? Maybe show an example. Though, doing a custom directive is not a bad thing. I would say this is something very cool that angular offers.

Comment: @Jeyp good point.  Thanks.  Edited.

Comment: @user1272965 - See my answer. I gave it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the helpful answers.  In case this helps somebody else, I did the following:

```
// this will show text with a <br> conditionally if the text is non-blank
angular.module('myApp.directives').directive('brIf', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            text: '='
        },
        template: '<span ng-show="text && text.trim().length">{{ text }}<br/></span>'
    };
});
```

So I can use it like this:

```
<br-if text="address.number + ' ' + address.street + ' ' + address.apt"></br-if>
```

I need to learn more about directives because I want to use it like this:

```
<br-if>{{address.number}} {{address.street}} {{address.apt}}</br-if>
```

to avoid all of the string math and the text= attribute, but I don't know how to get the contents of the element back into the template.

Answer (score 1):

```
      <span ng-show="some_expression.length>0">{{some_expression}}<br/><span>
```

You can use .length for your expression  , I mean for example :

```
      <span>{{some_expression.length}}<br/><span>
      // This will show the character length of your expression
```

every output in the {{}} have a length property because this is Javascript and in javascript , objects have a length property in their prototype
So u can use your ng-show based on the length of that object

Comment: Thanks.  I understand.  As you can see from the additional commentary and edit on the question, the expression is long, and I'm hoping to not repeat it in the html or the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide your check behind a method if you dont want to pollute your html code

For example: In your controller write this:

```
$scope.hideAddress = function(address) {
    if (address.number === undefined) {
        return true;
    }
    // arbitrary other checks
    return false;
}
```

Then you can use it in your html

```
<br ng-show="hideAddress(address)"/>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I made a clumsy directive to avoid (what I figure as) view logic inside the controller.

Comment: Yes, the cool thing is that angular offers many ways to achieve these kind of things. You could have also written your logic in the link function of the directive.

Comment: I think you're onto just what I'm trying to work out now.  Please have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26809100/angular-directive-refer-to-element-content-inside-template